# CSS responsive menu show, then hide, why

Tags: css, menu, responsive-design

I am about to launch this site, and done a lot of work on responsiveness... on big thing is the menu, that is responsive and show the "burger" when too small to show all item. The problem is when the screen is large enough for the whole menu to show, the is the burger that show, then hide to leave the full menu.

I HAVE NO IDEA why it's doing that ? it's CSS or javascript. 
Can you help for debugging this flick in menu

thanks in advance

*tested in chrome on mac
link to the page : http://studioteknik.co/solertia.ca/fr/

Answer (score 1):

Hi I think you have problem with the media query on responsive.css.

Try this:

```
From: 
@media all and (max-width: 1023px) {

To:
@media all and (max-width: 995px) {
```

Comment: i set it up at 995px and the flick happend again... what i am missing ?

Comment: Well just replace 995 with the width you think is the best.  From my tests under that value the big menu was wrapping.  So just play with the width. Other thing, which browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

In the "responsive.css" file there is this line `@media all and (max-width: 1023px) {`

Change the pixel value (lower most likely 800 - 960px). Then the menu won't appear unless its that size.